# I search the way of get facebook places ID

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I's using Facebook API now.

I thought I want see places list.
*Request URL
    https://graph.facebook.com/search?type=place&center=35.6589,139.701283&distance=500&access_token=token

This was successful but I'd like to add new spot to this places.
This is problem. I have no way now.

My image is this.

*My system post new spot to places with parameter of spot data.

```
parameter example:
name: test store,
category: Local business,
location:{
   street: test town 1-1-1,
   city: Sibuya-ku,
   state: Tokyo
   country: Japan,
   zip: 150-0001,
   latitude: 35.121313123,
   longitude: 139.123456,
}
```

*If this parameter is ok by Facebook, , The system of Facebook return spot_id.

Do facebook have a function like this?

Answer (score 0):

As you can see from your query, every place has a Facebook id, because every place that a user can check into is actually a Facebook page.

So what you want to do would require *creating* Facebook pages on-the-fly – and I don’t think that happening would be appreciated by Facebook, because we would end up with a lot of “dummy” pages that are used only once and will have no real activity and thereby now value to the FB userbase afterwards.

Depending on what you actually want to do with this “spot” info you like to create, maybe you could set that up yourself by using Open Graph objects instead, and have users taking actions on these objects of your’s.